# CakePHP 3.x Admin Section

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm migrating to CakePHP 3.x, the new version of CakePHP and faced some issued while implementing admin section, like not able to separate user and admin login.

A had also added following code into app/Config/routes.php file:

```
Router::prefix('admin', function ($routes) {
    // All routes here will be prefixed with `/admin`
    // And have the prefix => admin route element added.
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

When I logout from user section, admin also logout. What I want is, on same browser able to login into user and admin account and able to manage both session separately. Admin keep it's sign up, even if user logout from it's account.

I had also checked many blogs, but still not working.

If working example is available, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the cookie name in your Auth config (example in you Admin AppController)

Answer (score -1):

Check this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cake-php/zKrxSUQLi6s
You need create a folder Admin and put namespace with admin in your controllers.

Comment: I had already created Admin folder and two controller for admin section "IndexController" and "LoginController". What I want is, to create separate login for Front-end User and Backend Admin. Currently If I logout from one section, session of other section also expired and logout from it